# JPA persistence issue

Tags: java, database, jpa, record

I am having trouble in recording my database in JPA. 
My settings are set for JPA and I am using hibernate as a service. 
I have the following code.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
List<Beer> beiren = FindBeers();

List<Beer> aa = beiren.stream().map(x-> { 
    x.setPrice(x.getPrice()*1.02F);
    return x;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.copy(beiren,aa);
beiren.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
tx.commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

when I change the price value in beiren list I am expecting it to have an effect in the database when the entity manager is closed. since it is in a kind of persistent field I guess. 
if everything I do correctly here, I might have something else wrong in my class constructions.

could you please help me? what am I not doing correctly?
thank you...

Comment: What is the FindBeers() thing about?

Comment: After updating price of each object you have to update all objects as well in database.

Comment: FindBeers() is the function that call all the data from database.

Comment: how do i update the objects in the database

Comment: i added this code and it worked. beiren.stream()
  .forEach(x->em.merge(x)); _______________________________ But i think it is not a must. Persistance should have done that when it is closed. why do i have to do it manually.

Comment: A persistent object modified in the bounds of a transaction will be updated automatically on transaction commit. I am not sure what you are doing in these loops but it would appear not modifying an existing persistent instance. What happens if you use a simple loop `for(Beer beer : bieren){berr.setPrice(..);}`

Comment: actually in ________beiren.stream()
  .forEach(System.out::println);  ______________________________        i see the changes that it supposed to be.

Comment: i tried ________for(Beer beer : bieren){berr.setPrice(..);} ____________________ i got the same....

Comment: @Khalender see my answer for update objects.

Answer (score 1):

Before Commit add this line. If you are looking for something in EntityManager which will save or update a collection, the answer is no. You will have to loop. EntityManager.merge() API will update if record is existing or else will insert a new record.

```
aa.stream().foreach(em::merge);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yes that was the answer that i was looking for. So in persistence context, any change in the object, does not have an effect to datarecord unless em.merge(object) is executed.

Comment: @Khalender upvote/ Accept as answer if it solve your problem :) .